# What is a generic and portable way to get at underlying bits of a type in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, bit, portability, bitset

I want to take an arbitrary type that is no bigger than a pointer and get at its bit representation. I tried to use `std::bit_cast`, but that requires both types are the same size. But, because of genericity, I don't know what size the input type will be. I wrote this function:

```
template<class To, class From>
To sloppy_bit_cast(From x) {
  To temp{0};
  std::memcpy(&temp, &x, std::min(sizeof(From), sizeof(To)));
  return temp;
}
```

and it works on my computer, but I am worried the `memcpy` call will behave differently based on endianness. Are there other portability pitfalls I need to worry about here? Do `std::bitset`'s conversion functions solve this portably already?

Edit: specifically, I want to copy from least significant bit to least significant bit.

If you're interested, here's the whole code as of now (I haven't tested it, but my linter accepts it and it feels right at least). I'm not asking you to read or review it (though I would be happy to hear feedback). But I'm so happy you all helped me solve this, so I wanted to share.
I'm playing omitting the assertions for not just to get the general idea i out there, but I think I can work out that to constrain

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>


template<class T>
constexpr T narrow_cast(auto x) noexcept{
  return static_cast<T>(x);
}

template<class To, class From>
constexpr To bit_cast(From x) noexcept {
  static_assert(sizeof(To) == sizeof(From));
  To temp;
  std::memcpy(&temp, &x, sizeof(To));
  return temp;
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto bytes_of(T x) noexcept {
  return bit_cast<std::array<std::byte, sizeof x>>(x);
}

template<class T>
constexpr T to_integer(auto x) noexcept{
  return static_cast<T>(x);
}

template<class UInt, class T>
constexpr auto as_UInt(T x) noexcept {
  auto const bytes = bytes_of(x);
  UInt acc{};
  //endian agnostic
  for (auto i = 0u; i < bytes.size(); ++i) {
    auto const this_byte = to_integer<UInt>(bytes[i]);
    acc |= (this_byte << (i * 8u));
  }
  return acc;
}

template<class To, class UInt>
constexpr auto from_UInt(UInt from) noexcept {
  std::array<std::byte,sizeof(To)> bytes;
  //endian agnostic?
  for (auto i = 0u; i < bytes.size(); ++i){
    bytes[i] = narrow_cast<std::byte>((from >> (i * 8u)) & 0xFFu);
  }
  return bit_cast<To>(bytes);
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto as_uintptr_t(T x) noexcept {
  return as_UInt<uintptr_t>(x);
}

template<class To>
constexpr auto from_uintptr_t(uintptr_t x) noexcept {
  return from_UInt<To>(x);
}

template<class X, class Y, int low_bit_count_ = sizeof(Y) * 8>
class uintptr_pair {
  static_assert(sizeof(X) <= sizeof(uintptr_t));
  static_assert(sizeof(Y) <= sizeof(uintptr_t));

 public:
  static constexpr auto low_bit_count = low_bit_count_;
  static constexpr auto high_bit_count = sizeof(uintptr_t)*8 - low_bit_count;
  constexpr uintptr_pair() = default;
  constexpr uintptr_pair(X x, Y y) noexcept
      : x_{as_uintptr_t(x)}, y_{as_uintptr_t(y)} {}

  constexpr X x() const noexcept { return from_uintptr_t<X>(x_); }
  constexpr Y y() const noexcept { return from_uintptr_t<Y>(y_); }

 private:
  uintptr_t x_ : high_bit_count;
  uintptr_t y_ : low_bit_count;
};

constexpr auto test() {
  uintptr_pair<int, int> p{3, 4};
  return std::pair{p.x(),p.y()};
}
```

Comment: You really should be using `std::is_trivially_copyable<To>::value` and the same for `From` in that code.  If `To` or `From` are not trivially copyable, the code at runtime causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You can safely `reinterpret_cast` a pointer-to-object to pointer-to-`std::byte` to look at its byte representation. Is that what you're after? E.g. `std::byte const * bytes = reinterpret_cast<std::byte const *>(&some_object);` gives you a view `bytes` into the raw memory of the object. Note that, depending on the object, restoring it from such a representation may not be possible -- so it depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: In addition: `To temp{0};` should be `To temp{};`.  There is no guarantee `0` will be the right initial value for `To`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you! I'm adding these fixes now.

Comment: @cdhowie, would the byte order be platform-dependent?

Comment: @Riley Everything about the object layout could be both platform-dependent and compiler-dependent. It could even change between different versions of the same compiler, or when using different compilation flags with exactly the same compiler version.

Comment: Are there any guarantees for the fixed width unsigned integers? I only intend to use this code with pointers, integers, and enums.

Comment: @Riley [Something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35eeaaa17757d32c) should be sufficient to ensure you are memcpy-ing trivial types (this includes structs and classes that are trivially copyable).

Comment: @Riley Not really. The endianness of the underlying architecture can demand different byte layouts for integral types. Data extracted from an object from one compiler/architecture is never guaranteed to be compatible with a different compiler/architecture, though _usually_ it works if the architecture is the same.

Comment: Is there a chance that the source type has some strange size like 5 bytes?

Comment: @DavisHerring not for what I plan to do with it, but I am interested in how to handle this case. I want to make tagged pointers specifically, so I'll only need pointers and small enums.

Comment: std::intptr_t at least is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer on your system. so you could also make a union of a pointer and intptr_t then you can treat it as a int.
If you know the alignment of th pointed to object you might even be able to use a few bits of that poiner to store data

Comment: @Mellester I believe this is one of those undefined behaviors n theory that is usually fine in practice. But I want to avoid UB. I've read using unions for type punning is discouraged, but I forget if it was true UB or just unspecified/vendor extensions. This sounds like a potentially elegant and pragmatic approach if there's a way to check when it will work as intended.

Comment: @Mellester I have a link to a hilarious C++conference talk about exactly this! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAdLwUXRUvg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trivially arrange to have the correct amount of memory:

```
template<class T>
auto get_bytes(const T &t) {
  std::array<std::byte,sizeof t> ret;
  std::memcpy(ret.data(),&t,sizeof t);
  return ret;
}
```

This works even if `T` is not trivially-copyable, although you then can’t put the bytes back *in* a `T`.  (`std::bit_cast<std::array<…>>` would *probably* work, but there’s no true guarantee that the size of the *class* would be correct.)

If you want the result as an **integer**, you can pick one of at least as many bytes and then either fill it yourself via `|` and `<<` (which produces a value to analyze independent of issues like endianness) or `memcpy` into it from an array that you filled as above.  Again, if `T` has fewer bytes, theoretically the behavior isn’t guaranteed, but it will certainly work in practice.

Comment: bit_cast might break alignment wont it?

Comment: @Mellester: I don’t think I understand the possibility you’re suggesting, sorry.

Comment: casting a array to a pointer might break alignment of said pointer on some systems. Even when the data it self stil point to a vaild object

Comment: @Mellester Where is any such cast taking place in the above?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I think. I was hesitant to use a loop with bit shifts at first because it felt like work `malloc` could do for me, but it is both easier to write and transparent to the compiler. I haven't tested this, but I believe the loops, if written without data dependencies, could take advantage of instruction-level parallelism even if the compiler didn't know the length at compile time.

Comment: To check my big-picture understanding here, the reason this approach works is it lets the compiler handle the integer conversions because the bit casting is separate from the integer work?

Comment: @Riley: It works because you do nothing but copy some bytes.  The compiler knows what that means, unlike (say) `reinterpret_cast`.